# Save Changes from DataGridView back to SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, dataadapter

I've been looking through the internet and I know there are other posts on this topic but have had no success as of yet.

Here is my code to load data to my DataGridView named DataView:

```
    public void loadThis()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM Dates";
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter DSA = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(Sda);
                    conn.Open();
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                    DataView.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And here is what I have to try and save it back to the DataBase:

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            try
            {
                Sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Dates", conn);
                dt.AcceptChanges();
                Sda.Update(dt);
                SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(Sda);
                builder.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
                Sda.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();//Sql get update command needs to be initializwed
                Sda.Update(dt);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Loading the data works fine however the current code to save the ammendmenta throws the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Dynamic SQL generation for the
>   UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not
>   return any key column information.'

Thank you all!

Comment: Does "Dates" have a primary key?

Comment: It did though I have now re-created the table with a a new primary key column. The exception is not thrown any more though the catch of the try/catch does not fire either and the changes are not committed to the database

Comment: Might be worth debussing and having a look a the `CommandText` on the `UpdateCommand` to see what it's doing?

Comment: The commandtext property is set to :

Comment: 'code' UPDATE [Dates] SET [ID] = _italic_@_italic_p1, [Trainer] = _italic_@_italic_p2, [06/11/2017] = _italic_@_italic_p3 'code'
etc..
it is a database containing 3 years worth of dates

Comment: Sorry, it's formatted as [columnName] = @value
ignore the italisizing